# Get Dialogs by Occupant IDs Quickblox IOS sdk

Tags: ios, sdk, dialog, chat, quickblox

Just wondering if there is any way to get all the dialogs by occupants IDs.

The method i am using to get dialogs is

```
QBRequest dialogsForPage: extendedRequest: successBlock:errorBlock
```

Is there something i need to pass in extendedRequest?

Comment: u should check its protocol method ..there should be few method for this

Comment: Please see Quickblox documentation on their samplechat: http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Filters

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still wondering and came across to same question, Here's how you can find group by occupant id:

```
    [QBRequest dialogsForPage:[QBResponsePage responsePageWithLimit:10]
                  extendedRequest:@{@"occupantIDs[in]":@[id_1,id_2]}
                     successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, NSArray *dialogs, NSSet *dialogsUsersIDs, QBResponsePage *page)
         {}errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
         }];
```